# Only drag when clicking a parent element, not its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery-ui to let my div element be draggable. It looks like this:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">
      //here is some stuff like tabs and other dynamic content
   </div>
</div>
```

So the parent is draggable and I can drag whole element even if I drag on the space which is occupy by element with the id "child". I don't want drag when clicking the child element

In other words:

I want make my parent to be a natural draggable frame for its child elements, but this child must not trigger the parent draggable too.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel):

> Prevents dragging from starting on specified elements.

```
$('#parent').draggable({ cancel : '#child'});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/dA4L9/

Answer (score 2):

Check out [jQuery Draggable **Handle** Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle).

You'll see an example of exactly what you're trying to figure out.

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#parent" ).draggable({ cancel: "#child" });

    //Disable selection of text content within the set of matched elements.
    $( "div" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GbtUA/

You can use something like:

```
       $('#parent').draggable({
          cancel : 'div#child'
       });
```